# Op amps with load impedance matching

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance-matching

I have a [THS3491 Op amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths3491.pdf?ts=1596166087592&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTHS3491), and want to use non-inverting configuration.

[image]

Reading through the datasheet, all the specs are defined with \$R_L=100\Omega\$.

So, does this mean I have to attache \$ 49.9\Omega \$ resistor in SERIES with \$ 50\Omega\$ load (Oscilloscope, for example) to match impedance? Just like above image?

If I do that, then the output voltage will be halved, so I got worried about the maximum output I can get.

Reading again the datasheet, I found in the page 1, output voltage swing is \$28V_{p-p}\$ at \$\pm 16V \$ supply and \$R_L=100\Omega\$

(I am still not sure about the maximum voltage I can get. Is "output voltage swing" parameter I should be interested? or "input/output voltage range" parameter? (below table) )

[image]

If \$28V_{p-p}\$ is only output I could get with \$R_L=100\Omega\$, then at the end, the oscilloscope will read only \$14V_{p-p}\$. Is this correct?

In summary, I have three questions.

1. To use THS3491 op amp with noninverting configuration, do I have to put \$ 49.9\Omega \$ resistor in SERIES with \$ 50\Omega\$ load?
2. If I want to know maximum output voltage of THS3491 op amp, what is the parameter? "output voltage swing"? or "input/output voltage range"?
3. If I use \$ 49.9\Omega \$ resistor in SERIES with \$ 50\Omega\$-load oscilloscope, only \$14V_{p-p}\$ will be observed, is this correct?

Comment: The Zol is inductive from 0.1 to near 100 Ohms at 500MHz but with negative feedback 1 Ohm max.  Get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No (not for what you want to achieve)
2. The datasheet lists HRout (headroom to either supply) which is 1.5V. So max. output voltage will be 28V - 2*1.5V = 25V. But you need to watch out for the output impedance which is 0.17 Ohms. So if your load resistor is e.g. 0.17V, you will get less than 25V/2=12.5V at the output.
3. No, but it would be correct if this amp had an output impedance of 50 ohms.

Comment: 1) Can you explain more? if 50ohm in series with 49.9 ohm is not, then what is the correct configuration?    2) So, the maximum output should be "output voltage swing" - 2* "headroom to either supply"?

Comment: This OPAMP has (only) 0.17 Ohms of output impedance. The bigger the connected load resistor value, the bigger the output voltage swing. But headroom to either supply is a upper limit.